# Find UTC time zone using offset

Tags: javascript, php

I find rawoffset from google API(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location). Now i want to find UTC timezone not UTC time.

For example: I have New York City rawoffset and Wana to result UTC-5:00.

It is possible in php or javacript?

Comment: [momentjs timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) sounds pretty similar to what you want

Comment: Thanks Right link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment-timezone. Then you can use like this to get timezone

moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/Denver').format('Z z');

It will results -> -07:00 MST

Comment: You have to include moment-timezone.js and use  moment.tz("America/New_York").format('Z z');.